# Deleting dynamic memory alters other dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++, memory

For one of my classes, we're working on using as much basic C++ framework to create a class that reads a string input and puts the data into an array of arrays. Here is the code for the method

```
      std::string* input_line = new std::string;
      std::getline(std::cin, *input_line); 
      std::stringstream input_stream(*input_line);
      if (input_line->empty()) return;
      
      int size_of_sequence;
      input_stream >> size_of_sequence;
      
      // update class members
      sequence_ = new std::array<Object,2>[size_of_sequence];
      size_ = size_of_sequence;

      std::array<Object,2>* ptr = sequence_;
      int diff = sizeof(*sequence_);
      
      for (int i = 0 ; i < (int)size_; ++i) {
        input_stream >> (*ptr)[0];
        input_stream >> (*ptr)[1];
        ptr += diff;
      }
      delete input_line;
```

However, the issue i'm having is that the deletion of `input_line` changes values stored at `sequence_`, specifically the first value of the second array. I'm completely at a loss as to why this is as `input_line` is stored at an entirely separate location from sequence. What am I missing?

Edit: Thanks for the responses. To clear up some confusion, we weren't allowed to use vectors and were expected to use a pointer to a sequence of arrays.

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  Also, why are you using `new` here at all?  You can use a vector instead of raw pointers and `new`.  Also, there is no reason for `input_line` to be a pointer at all.  You could just use `std::string input_line; std::getline(std::cin, input_line);  ...`

Comment: Tactical note: most of `std::string`'s job is to manage the resources of the string for you. If you dynamically allocate a `std::string`, `std::string* input_line = new std::string;`, you're taking at least some of that work back upon yourself. You almost never want to dynamically allocate a `std::string` or [library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Also note that if `input_line->empty()` returns true you leak the memory associated with `input_line`.

Comment: For the most part, as long as you can use C++14 or higher, there really isn't a reason to use `new` anymore.

Comment: Why are you allocating an array of std::arrays? Too many pointers in this code. There doesn't need to be any.

Comment: You've shot yourself in the foot by trying to be too smart with pointers, and not accounting for pointer arithmetic being based on the size of what the pointer points at.  The last loop ONLY has well-defined behaviour if `diff` has a value of `1`, since it accesses `sequence_[i*diff]` for each value of `i` between `0` and `size_of_sequence - 1`.  `diff` actually has a value of `sizeof(std::array<Object,2>)` which has a minimum value of `2*sizeof(Object)`.  `sizeof(Object)` has a value of `1` or more, so the minimum possible value of `diff` is `2`. Hence the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause of the problem is the undefined behaviour you have here

```
  sequence_ = new std::array<Object,2>[size_of_sequence];
  size_ = size_of_sequence;

  std::array<Object,2>* ptr = sequence_;
  int diff = sizeof(*sequence_);
  
  for (int i = 0 ; i < (int)size_; ++i) {
    input_stream >> (*ptr)[0];
    input_stream >> (*ptr)[1];
    ptr += diff;
  }
```

`sizeof` is a big red flag. The correct code would be

```
  sequence_ = new std::array<Object,2>[size_of_sequence];
  size_ = size_of_sequence;

  std::array<Object,2>* ptr = sequence_;
  
  for (int i = 0 ; i < (int)size_; ++i) {
    input_stream >> (*ptr)[0];
    input_stream >> (*ptr)[1];
    ++ptr;
  }
```

When you want to iterate a pointer through an array you just need to use `++`. C++ automatically adjusts the pointer increment by the size of the object being pointed to. There is no need to use `sizeof` to calculate this for yourself.

The following code would be simpler however

```
  sequence_ = new std::array<Object,2>[size_of_sequence];
  size_ = size_of_sequence;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < (int)size_; ++i) {
    input_stream >> sequence_[i][0];
    input_stream >> sequence_[i][1];
  }
```

No need for the `ptr` variable.